# Slickest way to put objects into separate lists based on a property value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of objects and am curious about the way you would separate them into two lists - one list will have everything of a specific type, the other will have the remainder. One way I thought of doing it is:

```
var typeXs = (from o in collectionOfThings where o.Type == "typeX" select o);
var notTypeXs = (from o in collectionOfThings where o.Type != "typeX" select o);
```

The other way would be to just loop over collectionOfThings and assign based on if/else.

Both ways are simple and readable, but I'm just wondering if there is an even slicker way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example should demonstrate what you're after:

```
class MyObject
{
    public int n;
    public string t;
}
```

Load up my original list:

```
List<MyObject> allObjects = new List<MyObject>() {
    new MyObject() { n = 0, t = "x" },
    new MyObject() { n = 1, t = "y" },
    new MyObject() { n = 2, t = "x" },
    new MyObject() { n = 3, t = "y" },
    new MyObject() { n = 4, t = "x" }
};
```

Split out the types using:

```
var typeXs = allObjects.FindAll(i => i.t == "x");
var notTypeXs = allObjects.FindAll(i => i.t != "x");
```

*Or*

```
var typeXs = allObjects.Where(i => i.t == "x").ToList<MyObject>();
var notTypeXs = allObjects.Except(typeXs).ToList<MyObject>();
```

*Alternatively* you could use the List.ForEach method which only iterates once and therefore theoretically *should* outperform the other two options.  Also, it doesn't require referencing the LINQ libraries which means it's .NET 2.0 safe.

```
var typeXs = new List<MyObject>();
var notTypeXs = new List<MyObject>();
allObjects.ForEach(i => (i.t == "x" ? typeXs : notTypeXs).Add(i));
```

Comment: The second example's probably the best, but good job giving all the options. +1

Comment: and it only iterates the collection a single time, both of the other options actually have to iterate the collection twice, even though perhaps they are a little more elegantly written.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the second part as

```
var notTypeXs = collectionOfThings.Except(typeXs);
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest, most expressive way.

Answer (score 0):

```
coll.GroupBy(o => o.Type == "TypeX");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, Thing>> that it returns

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to ejoptimilate all over you, but I do think you should consider only iterating once.

```
    // You can optimize this by specifying reasonable initial capacities.
List<TypedO> typeXs = new List<TypedO>();
List<TypedO> notTypeXs = new List<TypedO>();

foreach(TypedO o in list)
{
    (o.Type == "typeX" ? typeXs : notTypeXs).Add(o); // Yeah, I know.
}
```

(corrected)

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that: 
"The other way would be to just loop over collectionOfThings and assign based on if/else."

Comment: Sorry if I was redundant.  I just had to recommend this option, and strictly speaking I didn't use if or else. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go thru the list twice, then:

```
    var collectionOfThings = new[] 
        {
            new Thing { Id = 1, Type = "typeX" },
            new Thing { Id = 2, Type = "typeY" },
            new Thing { Id = 3, Type = "typeZ" },
            new Thing { Id = 4, Type = "typeX" }
        };


    var query = (from thing in collectionOfThings
                 group thing by thing.Type == "typeX" into grouped
                 //orderby grouped.Key descending
                 select new
                 {
                     IsTypeX = grouped.Key,
                     Items = grouped.ToList()
                 }).ToList();

    var typeXs = query.Find(x => x.IsTypeX).Items;
    var notTypeXs = query.Find(x => !x.IsTypeX).Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'OfType' link expression, along these lines:

```
var typeXs = collectionOfThigs.OfType<typeX>();
var notTypeXs = collectionOfThings.Except(typeXs);
```

(Including the .Except from another answer). This does assume you have the type and not just the  type string however.

Also, there may be a performance penalty for not making the decision just once (the if with the split add is probably the way to go if it matters), but unless performance is a problem, clarity is my preference.